# How do you get Eclipse to recognize new Android elements

Tags: android, android-listview, clickable

I am trying to write an android app that has a button that navigates to a Listview.  I just add the Listview XML to my project.  How do I get my Eclipse project to recognize it so I can use it in my setContentView()

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Patient List is Empty"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I was attempting to use it in this new ListActivity

```
public class PatientList extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout);

    List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
}
/**
 * 
 */
public PatientList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

}
```

But I can't find it using Eclipse's equivalent intelli-sense.  Each element in this listView will be click-able btw probably opening up another List View (that will be retrieved by an http call to an xml file somewhere based on an id in the xml).

I will then attempt to open this on the click of a button that I have... Not the best design, but I will be improving that once I figure out some of the more a way to call xml as an http webservice get the xml and turn it into a listview... This list view is being pre-determined at this point.  But any help figuring out how I can now access this listview or make my R.java access it (auto generated, so how do I get that thing to recognize my ListView?) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: be careful with the R class. Eclipse offers you to import "android.R". Dont import that. Import your own (sometimes you need to clean the project for eclipse to find it)

There are some tutorials out there. you should go through one like this one from google:
http://developer.android.com/intl/de/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

or this one
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: One of the problem is that it looks like my R.java never gets the ListView in it at any time?  How does my R.java get access to the ListView?  Do I have to compile or something?

Comment: Oh wait.  Now I see it.  Sorry

Comment: I am guessing once I saved the xml somehow or the other my R.java file all of a sudden recognized the ListView...  How precisely that happened is beyond me.

Comment: the R class is generated from the xml files each time the project is build...somtimes it does not get the change of the xml files -> clean, build...  have a look at your "gen" folder in your project